# How to know the input node names of the frozen model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, labview

I am making a Deep Learning model and need to use it in LabView DL module.
but it need the input node and output node names how to find them please help me.
[image]

i tried to use some code to find the node names but iam not getting them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use model.summary() to get all the names of the layers present in the model.For example

```
model=keras.Sequential([
                        keras.Input(shape=(28,28,1)),
                        keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                        keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                        keras.layers.Flatten(),
                        keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                        keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')])


model.summary()

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 13, 13, 32)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 11, 11, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 5, 5, 64)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 1600)              0         
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 1600)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 10)                16010     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 34,826
Trainable params: 34,826
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________
```

The names under the layer column are the names of the layer. Thank You.